# Is Garp the only Vice Admiral to have a customized ship?

Tags: one-piece

After watching One Piece for about 500 episodes I noticed that I have only seen [***Garp***](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Garp) with a customized naval ship. The theme of his ship is a dog theme like the mask he was seen wearing early on in the series. I was wondering if there are any other personnel within the Navy that have a customized ship instead of the standard design. (Canon only)

**Garp's Ship:**
[image]

Comment: I managed to find that one, but I can't remember from which episode it shown.
http://st-listas.20minutos.es/images/2011-06/292285/3048289_640px.jpg?1308395394

Comment: @HashiramaSenju that is an 8th branch ship which is non-canon.

Comment: So far it is the only customized navy ship in the anime and manga.

Comment: Succinct but you need the "canon" caveat due to the 8th branch ship in Hashirama's comment to be accurate.  (It was anime-only.)

Comment: It would be preferable if you include links or reference to your answer to justify what you posted.

Comment: tsuru's ship like garp is customised to have an overall crane theme

Comment: @qwerty This was not the case 27 years in the past...  That is the only picture I could find of her ship and her normal looking ship was chasing Doflamingo's flamingo themed ship.  When else did they show her ship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far this is the only ship which has been shown to be customized to have the customized figurehead of the dog.

> It first appeared in Chapter 91 and Episode 68. It was last seen parked outside Dawn Island, but since Garp resigned from the Marines, it is unknown if he still has access to the ship.

[image: Garp]

Hina's ship on the other hand is a similar to a normal Marine Ship, albeit with an unusual coloring. It first appeared in Chapter 171 and Episode 127. 
[image: Hina's Ship]

Source: [One Piece Wikia: Marine Ships](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Marine_Ships)